# Overiding Variables ins subclass used in method

Tags: java, string, class, variables

SuperClass:

```
public class question1 {
static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
static int score = 0;
static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
static String question = "1. Which one of the following is classified as an economic resource? \n A) Consumption \n B) Productivity \n C) Production \n D) Enterprise";
static String answer = "D";

protected void question() {
    System.out.println(question);
    String message = input.nextLine();
            Answer(message);
    }
protected void Answer(String message) {
    if (message.equals("answer")) {
            score++;
            results.add("1." + "Correct\n\n");
            }else{ 
            results.add(question + "\n Incorrect - D\n\n");
            }
    }

public question1() { }

public question1(String newQuestion, String newAnswer) {
    question = newQuestion;
    answer = newAnswer;
    }
}
```

SubClass:

```
public class question2 extends question1 {
String question = "2. Which one of the following is classified as a supply side policy? \n A) A reduction in the rate of interest to reduce inflation \n B) An increase in goverment expenditure on state pensions \n C) A reduction in company taxes to encourage greater investment \n D) A rise in the exchange rate to increase exports";
String answer = "C";

public question2() {
}

public question2(String question, String answer) {
    super(question, answer);
}

}
```

main:

```
public class Paper {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    question1 q1 = new question1();
    question2 q2 = new question2();
    q1.question();
    q2.question();
}
}
```

When the `question();` method is called from the q2 object created using the question2 class the variable values for 'answer' and 'question' from the question1 class are used instead of the ones from the question2 class, why is this ?

Comment: Show us a sample output.

Comment: You can't override static members.

Comment: Because you don't have `question()` method in your derived class. No matter with which object you call `question()` it will print the same thing.

Comment: So does this mean I have to have the same copy of the method in my derived class, surely it will inherit the method ?

Answer (score 1):

`question2` must override the `question()` method to use the fields declared in `question2`. `q2.question();` executes the implementation in `question1` (inherited by `question2`, not overridden), which is not aware of the fields in the subclass.

Comment: Is there no way question2 can inherit the question() method, but use the new fields declared in question2 ?

Comment: No. Subclass can see the (non-private) fields in superclass but not vice-varsa. Just think, what would happen if you were to remove the fields from the superclass.

Comment: and so the only way for this to work is to have the method text in the question2 subclass aswel ?

Comment: I wouldn't redeclare the fields in the subclass. That's against code-reusability.